# Overwriting Bootstrap css?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a question regarding overwriting bootstrap css. I want to use mine all style, background, media, etc. I have reviewed for related question and answers, everybody is saying that I load mine css after bootstrap core css like this.

```
 <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then for example I want to put a background in mine wrap-pad section.

```
.service .wrap-pad {
    background-image: url(../background/booksground.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-filter: none;
    -o-filter: none;
    filter: none;
}
```

After I do this nothing happens, further more I can not overwrite any of the styles or put mine media in it, I have tried to do this with navbar, footer etc. Everything looks plain whit standard bootstrap styles in it. I am using [small-business theme](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/small-business/), from [startbootstrap.com](http://startbootstrap.com/), bootstrap 3.2.2, then I modified it with some wrap pad animations and carousel to fit mine needs. 
How can I overcome this and start using mine styles.
Tank you.

Comment: Can you please "Inspect Element" on this element of yours, find the "Styles" tab and paste the entries in that? Look through the entries till you find your modifications.

Answer (score 2):

Your overriding style selectors have to be as specific as, or more specific than, the Bootstrap selectors.  Also, as you stated, your custom styles need to appear after the ones you are overriding.

For example, this is some CSS from the default bootstrap.css:

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5 0%, #e8e8e8 100%);
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5 0%, #e8e8e8 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f5f5f5), to(#e8e8e8));
  background-image:         linear-gradient(to bottom, #f5f5f5 0%, #e8e8e8 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fff5f5f5', endColorstr='#ffe8e8e8', GradientType=0);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

And I used this CSS to override it in custom.css:

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border-left: 2px solid #4285f4;
    padding-left: 18px; 
}
```

Comment: Yes I understand that, but when I specified it properly and amend it, that's not overwrite the style.

Comment: It would help if you could direct us to the classes in the Bootstrap or small-business theme CSS files that you want to override.  E.g. I don't see .wrap-pad in either of those files.

Comment: .wrap-pad is mine animation that I have made to modified small-business theme, but thank you I have realized mine mistake, I have done something similarly like you and it worked lovely, as you said 'Your overriding style selectors have to be as specific as, or more specific than, the Bootstrap selectors.'

Answer (score 1):

CSS works as the following..

---

**1** *Linked File*

**2** *Internal code*

**3** *inline inside a tag*

This being said.. Inline always overwrites Internal and Linked,
And Internal (same page) always overrides css from outside..
So since bootstrap has the css imported externally,
the other two options should overwrite it.

Hope This Helps.

Comment: external style(liked file) can overrides inline styles using  important ex : 
 background-color:#333 !important;

Comment: I never really used !important
Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Just write a style, a class for example

```
.any{
   background: any-color
}
```

and in your tag add the the *any* class

```
<div class='class-1 class-2 class-3 any'>
```

As all the classes are applied in cascade (think about the stand 'css') the last tends to overwrite the other styles.